# Not directly going against the entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I added my table called `Persons` to my entity Model.  I don't want to have to directly access the entity `Person` created in the entity model.  How can I access the the entity models through a middle man, like a repository?  I am also not sure, what would be the advantage of doing this as opposed to just going directly against the entities?

Comment: Have you tried anything or read anything around this yourself?  Why don't you want to access the entity directly?  You suggest yourself that you don't know what the advantage of this approach is - which suggests that perhaps you should stick with the approach you have until you have reason to change!

Comment: saw a similar question in the last hour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302464/using-entity-framework-with-repository-pattern-in-winforms-mdi/16485193#16485193